# Generic Stack implementation in C-style C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I implemented generic stack in C. Seems to work fine. It doesn't work for strings, though.

It was compiled using Visual C++.

**Implementation:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct node{
    void* value;

    node* next;
};

struct stack{
    node* first;
    int elemSize;
    int length;
};

stack* StackNew(int elemSize)
{
    stack* s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->length = 0;
    return s;
}

void Push(stack* s, void* value)
{
    node* oldFirst = s->first;
    s->first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    s->first->value = malloc(s->elemSize);
    memcpy(s->first->value, value, s->elemSize);
    s->first->next = oldFirst;
    s->length++;
}

void* Pop(stack* s)
{
    void* value = malloc(s->elemSize);
    memcpy(value, s->first->value, s->elemSize);
    node* oldFirst = s->first;
    s->first = s->first->next;
    free(oldFirst);
    s->length--;
    return value;
}

void Destory(stack* s)
{
    while (s->length > 0) Pop(s);
    free(s);
}
```

**Test:**

```
struct point{
    int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    stack* s = StackNew(sizeof(point));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        point pt;
        pt.x = i;
        pt.y = i * i;
        Push(s, &pt);
    }

    while (s->length > 0) {
        point pt = *(point*)Pop(s);
        printf("(%d,%d)\n", pt.x, pt.y);
    }
    Destory(s);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> (99,9801)
> (98,9604)
> (97,9409)
> (96,9216)
> (95,9025)
> (94,8836)
> (93,8649)
> (92,8464)
> (91,8281)
> (90,8100)
> (89,7921)
> (88,7744)
> (87,7569)
> (86,7396)
> ...
> ```

as expected.

Please tell me what I did wrong and how I can improve things.

Comment: If this is C, why are you including `iostream`?

Comment: @EngieOP I wrote it in C++ but i'm using the C subset of C++.

Comment: Okay, just wondering. I remember there being a Meta post about C/C++ tag mixing.

Comment: If it compiles as C++, but would fail to compile as C, then it's still C++ code and should be tagged as such. (Someone will probably say "Why don't you just go all the way with C++?" in an answer, but that's just how it has to be.)

Comment: Alternatively, just remove `#include <iostream>` and retag as [tag:c].

Comment: @200_success then i would also have to rewrite node struct to have typdefs. But that's okay. calling it C-style C++ is fine.

Answer (score 6):

- **Naming** seems inconsistent.

  Consider prefixing all exported names with `Stack`, e.g. `StackPush`, `StackPop`, `StackDestroy` (`Destory` is definitely a typo).

  The entity named `first` in a stack context is traditionally referred to as `top`.
- **Memory management** is overengineered.

  Every time a value is pushed memory is allocated. That's justifiable for ownership reasons (make sure to document it). However every time a value is popped memory is allocated again. *This* is very strange. A simple

  ```
  return s->first->value;
  ```

  would suffice.

  Along the same line `Destroy` doesn't free memory (re)allocated for individual stack entries. Consider

  ```
  while(s->length > 0)
      free(Pop(s))
  ```
- You've mention the problem with strings; I believe it is stemmed from `elemSize` being a property of the stack itself. Making it a property of an element would solve the problem.
- As mentioned in the comments, the C code shall not include C++ headers.

Comment: "Making it a property of an element would solve the problem." It does solve the problem. I also had to to rewrite StackPush(Stack* s,void* value) to StackPush(Stack* s,void* value,int elemSize).